# Spoofing IP address on same machine running 127.0.0.1 server

Tags: python

I am hosting a server listening for UDP packets on local host with IP address '127.0.0.1'. On the same machine, how would I be able to send packets to this server with spoofed IP address '1.2.3.4' and not '127.0.0.1'?

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
   
    sizes = {}
    for size in range(512):
    sizes[size] = 0

    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(8092)
        if addr[0] != "1.2.3.4":
            print("Acess denied")
            #print(addr[0])
            #print(len(data))
            continue
        else:
            print("hello")
        
    print ("length:", len(data))
    sizes[len(data)] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is the code I am using to send UDP packets.

```
import socket
import ipaddress

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ipaddress.ip_address(unicode('1.2.3.4', "utf-8"))
    Message = "H"
    clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    clientSock.sendto(Message, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```